# Sanskrit Language Typing Help, Ubuntu-14

Tags: language-support

I had taken the following steps with Ubuntu-12 and it had worked perfect. But on a new laptop, I installed Ubuntu-14 and I am not getting access to iTrans conformant typing or transliteration scheme for the Sanskrit language. Ubuntu-14 gives me access to Hindi language's Bolnagri and Wx schemes and Sanskrit language's KaGaPa Phonetic, but these schemes are new to me; and I know for fact that 15-20 years ago iTrans conformant typing was the norm and it was available with Ubuntu-12. So why this new change, which is perhaps not for the better? How can I add to Ubuntu-14 what was the default for Sanskrit Lang under Ubuntu-12?

System Settings > Language Support > Install/Remove Languages

I added Sanskrit and Hindi at the step above.

Then I checked under :
Text Entry Settings > Input Sources To Use > AND I only see options like KaGaPa Phonetic, Bolnagari et al. 
I would like my ubuntu-12 setting back. I do not remember the technical name for that transliteration scheme for Sanskrit Lang typing support to Dev-nagari script.

Please advise. I hope this is the correct place where to ask for this help.

Comment: Does http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/109 help? (On a mobile, so I'll vett the commands and add an answer later.)

Answer (score 2):

Install the *ibus-m17n* package and relogin. Then you should see a *Sanskrit (IAST (m17n))* option in the list of input sources. Probably that's what you want.

Comment: I tried ibus-m17n. And it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I installed ibus-m17n package, and its 'Harvard-Kyoto m17n' option does help me a lot. But it is still not as good as iTrans conformant scheme. Gmail's Sanskritam-Phonetic scheme comes very close to being fully iTrans conformant. But I would like to be able to type in Devnagari script direct in any edit-box.

I am way better off than where I was yesterday, but still not quite there. I will search some more to be able to do iTrans conformant typing.  (To muru - I am not using this on a mobile.)

Comment: Did you find your way?

I have been using inscript as entry method, and it is the standard layout available.

System Settings  > Text Entry > Input Sources

And add there "Indian". It is stupid name, but when selecting indian, devanagari (Inscript) is the default keyboard layout.

Comment: @OssiViljakainen Thank you every much. This is exactly what I wanted. You are right its a stupid name. Windows also call it Devanagri.