# How can I change the system language to Sanskrit? (not asking for typing help)

Tags: 18.04, language-support

How can I change my system language to Sanskrit? Sanskrit is not seen in install/remove languages. I am not asking for typing help. I need the Ubuntu display to be in Sanskrit.

Comment: You probably need this https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ibus-m17n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sanskrit Language Typing Help, Ubuntu-14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497149/sanskrit-language-typing-help-ubuntu-14)

Comment: Input language is not the same as system language...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But I am not asking for typing help, I can do that with IBUS. I want the display language to be Sanskrit. It was possible in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

For languages with very few translations no language packs are built, and they are not included as options in the GUIs. I see that Sanskrit was an option in Trusty, but not later.

So to make Sanskrit reappear as an option, helping with improving the translation coverage is the best way.

If you have particular applications where Sanskrit translations are available, you can enable it manually:

1. Generate the Sanskrit locale:

   ```
   sudo locale-gen sa_IN
   ```
2. Add these lines to your `~/.profile` file:

   ```
   export LANG=sa_IN.UTF-8
   export LANGUAGE=sa
   ```